# Stop a runnable in a separate Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

Hey there i currently have a problem with my android app. I´m starting an extra thread via 
implementing the Excecutor Interface:

```
class Flasher implements Executor {
    Thread t;
   public void execute(Runnable r) {
     t = new Thread(r){
     };
     t.start();
   }
 }
```

I start my Runnable like this:

```
flasherThread.execute(flashRunnable);
```

but how can i stop it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java

Comment: Don't implement your own `Executor` without a very good reason to do so - use those already available in the Java API.  Besides: Stopping a task performed in another thread in Java always relies on the other thread or rather its task to *cooperate*. If your `Runnable` keeps sitting in an endless loop, basically doing nothing, there is "no" way to stop it.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK There is no such method in the [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop a thread by another thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839881/how-to-stop-a-thread-by-another-thread)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this is just the very basic threading 101, but let there be another example:

Old-school threading:

```
class MyTask implements Runnable {
    public volatile boolean doTerminate;

    public void run() {
        while ( ! doTerminate ) {
            // do some work, like:
            on();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            off();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();

Thread thread = new Thread( task );

thread.start();

// let task run for a while...

task.doTerminate = true;

// wait for task/thread to terminate:
thread.join();
// task and thread finished executing
```

Edit:

Just stumbled upon this very informative [Article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) about how to stop threads.

Comment: Java's standard way of interrupting a thread is... to interrupt the thread. And in your Runnable, you can use `while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {soSomething();}` to stop what you are doing when an interruption signal is sent.

Comment: Undoubtedly. - However, there still is *no* way to force an arbitrary `Runnable` (or thread) to terminate; in *every* case cooperation by the `Runnable` is required. And that's the point of the OP: To be able to stop a running thread, the code in that thread must be explicitly written to support that.

Comment: I'm not arguing about the cooperation bit - just saying that the cooperation is generally implemented with the interruption mechanism rather than boolean flags.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that implementing `Executor` is a good idea. I would rather use one of the executors Java provides. They allow you to control your `Runnable` instance via `Future` interface:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<?> future = executorService.submit(flashRunnable);
...
future.cancel(true);
```

Also make sure you free resources that `ExecutorService` is consuming by calling `executorService.shutdown()` when your program does not need asynchronous execution anymore.

Comment: "allow you to control your Runnable instance" - Sorry, but that is not true. They allow you to control the *`Executor`*, but the `Runnable` can still do whatever it likes, including not terminating and thus messing up the executor and what not.

Comment: `future.cancel()` method may return false, indicating that your cancel request has failed, but `Future` controls one single `Runnable` instance, not the `Executor` that may execute or schedule thousands of  tasks

Comment: So, how can one influence the `Runnable` instance via the `Future`?

Comment: Call `future.cancel(true)` and your `Runnable` instance will stop, if it is not designed to ignore `InterruptedException`

Comment: The `Runnable`'s thread will be 'interrupted' - but that does not necessarily imply an `InterruptedException` will be thrown, or that there is any other effect on the `Runnable` instance at all.  So, if the `Runnable` is not *explicitly prepared* to handle an externally set termination condition there is ["no"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) way to stop it.

Comment: Even your old school sample contains `sleep` call (that your forgot to handle, btw). That said, only _explicitly designed_ `Runnable` will not be interrupted, not the other way around. But this dispute deserves separate SO question.

Comment: Yes, my example uses `sleep()` (omitting exception handling for simplicity). But there is no reason every `Runnable` will have to call any method that may throw an `InterruptedException`. What if I removed those calls to `sleep()`? - Unstoppable (by interruption) :) - And as you noted: *Explicit* handling of the `InterruptedException` would be required in a *correct* way to terminate.

Comment: If your `Runnable` does not have waiting calls (like sleep, wait or blocked IO), it will kill your application most probably, especially if it is long running job. If you ignore `InterruptedException`, this is what I called explicitly designed `Runnable`; and I consider it a bad practice too.

Comment: Almost all blocking IO operations are *not* interruptible and, thus, will never throw `InterruptedException`s; special handling will be required. - Ignoring `InterruptedException`s - bad practice, definitely. Explicitly and correctly handling those exceptions - good practice, but no guarantee the thread will ever actually see the `InterruptedException` though `interrupt()`ed.

Comment: I did not say that it is guaranteed though. Still you can use `Thread.interrupted()` call to check if `interrupt()` was called instead of writing tones of old-school code

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely correct; and the 'clean' way to do it. In this case, the `interrupted` state is the externally set 'flag'.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing your own Executor, you should look at [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). ExecutorService has a shutdown method which:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the ExecutorService, along with the Furure object, which gives you control over the thread that is being created by the executor. Like the following example

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future future = executor.submit(runnabale);
try {
     future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
     Log.warn("Time out expired");
} finally {
     if(!future.isDone()&&(!future.isCancelled())) 
        future.cancel(true);

    executor.shutdownNow();
}
```

This code says that the runnable will be forced to terminate after 2 seconds. Of course, you can handle your Future ojbect as you wish and terminate it according to your requierements